# 1 b3 4 Triad in A Love Supreme?

Tags: chord-theory, jazz

In the Acknowledgement of *A Love Supreme*, this motif seems to be two stacked 1 b3 4 triads—what would you call them? Super-diminished?? Or is there a better way to understand this motif chordally than two stacked triads? Thanks!
[image: A Love Supreme: D F G, G Bb C]

Comment: The best way to interpret that melody is probably simply as a pentatonic scale. If you're wondering about the chords below it as well, they look like quartal/quintal chords to me, so you might read about those. For example, the notes of the first chord which contains Eb, Bb, F and C, are related by 5ths instead of 3rds like a normal tertian chord. That goes for the chords in the next measure too. For the modal approach, you might want to look into "avoid notes" as well. That helps me a lot with both melody and harmony.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing as "super-diminished triad". There are 4 types of triads: minor, major, diminished and augmented. Neither C-Eb-F, nor F-Ab-Bb is a triad.

The chord in measure 63 is Fm7add11, containing all notes of F minor pentatonic scale. The saxophone motifs use the same scale. The first one, C-Eb-F, is 5-b7-1, it emphasizes the root of the chord. The second, F-Ab-Bb is 1-b3-4, it emphasizes the 4, which fits the modal jazz style, as opposed to tonal music, where emphasizing 4 is normally avoided.